How to assert that a mock was called with an specific argument in Go?
Let's say I have a test like this
func TestSomeFn(t *testing.T){

   t.Run("the fn is called with x when someFunc is called with y", func(t *testing.T){
       mockFn := new(MockFn) // this is a mock for a function utilized inside of someFunc
       response := true
       expected := "expected-value"
       mockFn.On("method", mock.Anything).Return(response, nil)

       res, err: = SomeFn(mockFn, x)
       require.NoError(t, err)
       assert.Equal(t,expected,res)
    }
}


How should I write the line to assert that mockFn was called with some argument ?
I would like to know if I need to include an extra library for this purpose

Assuming you are using github.com/stretchr/testify/mock you could define your own mock object or use mock.MatchedBy.
